# Add fee on cart items based on custom field for each item and add it on cart and checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce and I am using a custom post type (products) for my products

This is the code that integrates my custom post type to woocommerce

```
class WCCPT_Product_Data_Store_CPT extends WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT {

    /**
     * Method to read a product from the database.
     * @param WC_Product
     */

    public function read( &$product ) {

        $product->set_defaults();

        if ( ! $product->get_id() || ! ( $post_object = get_post( $product->get_id() ) ) || ! in_array( $post_object->post_type, array( 'products', 'product' ) ) ) {
            throw new Exception( __( 'Invalid product.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }

        $id = $product->get_id();

        $product->set_props( array(
            'name'              => $post_object->post_title,
            'slug'              => $post_object->post_name,
            'date_created'      => 0 < $post_object->post_date_gmt ? wc_string_to_timestamp( $post_object->post_date_gmt ) : null,
            'date_modified'     => 0 < $post_object->post_modified_gmt ? wc_string_to_timestamp( $post_object->post_modified_gmt ) : null,
            'status'            => $post_object->post_status,
            'description'       => $post_object->post_content,
            'short_description' => $post_object->post_excerpt,
            'parent_id'         => $post_object->post_parent,
            'menu_order'        => $post_object->menu_order,
            'product_id'        => $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id(),
            'reviews_allowed'   => 'open' === $post_object->comment_status,
            'price'             => $post_object->price
        ) );

        $this->read_attributes( $product );
        $this->read_downloads( $product );
        $this->read_visibility( $product );
        $this->read_product_data( $product );
        $this->read_extra_data( $product );
        $product->set_object_read( true );
    }

    public function get_product_type( $product_id ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type( $product_id );
        if ( 'product_variation' === $post_type ) {
            return 'variation';
        } elseif ( in_array( $post_type, array( 'products', 'product' ) ) ) { // change birds with your post type
            $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_type' );
            return ! empty( $terms ) ? sanitize_title( current( $terms )->name ) : 'simple';
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_data_stores', 'woocommerce_data_stores' );

function woocommerce_data_stores ( $stores ) {
    $stores['product'] = 'WCCPT_Product_Data_Store_CPT';
    return $stores;
}
```

so I know can add to cart the custom post type by adding price on it

I added a custom field using woocommerce_form_field() which is called "Track Length" and will be multiplied per $24 ( 2 x $24 = $28 )

[image]

Now I tried using "woocommerce_before_calculate_totals" filter and its not working, the set_price() is not working maybe because its a custom post type

so now I am getting the computation inside "woocommerce_product_get_price" filter but its not working per item in cart

Here is the code inside my functions.php https://codeshare.io/5eN797

Comment: You should need also to try extending WC_Product with your custom post type, to be able to use WC_Product methods like get_price and set_price

Comment: Hi Loic, the problem is I dont know how to extend the WC_Product